# Does to-link nano router speeds up the internet?

Tags: networking

i want to buy a tp link nano router 150mbps , but before I want to know if it speeds up the internet , plz help me guys, and if it speeds internet how much will it become the internet speed of my router is (750 Kbps ) maximum

Comment: How fast is your internet? And are you connected to your router by wifi or cable?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how fast your router might be when you have a limited bandwidth from your Internet Service Provider (ISP) to the router you will be limited by the bandwidth provided to the router by your ISP.  You can be constrained by a router offering less bandwidth from itself to your devices in which case putting in a faster router will help, if the bandwidth provided by your ISP to the old router exceeded what the old router could provide to your devices.

E.g., if your router only provided 100 Mbs connectivity to your devices and you put in a new router that can provide 1,000 Mbs (1 Gbs), which is 10 times the prior value, if you only have 1 Mbs service from your ISP, your access to websites, etc. on the Internet is still not going to be any faster than 1 Mbs at best. But, if the ISP provides 200 Mbs service to the router, then the new router should provide a noticeable improvement, if your devices can communicate with the router at 1 Gbs. However, if they are incapable of communicating at more than 100 Mbs themselves, then you are still limited to 100 Mbs at best.